# Adding hour using react-moment

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I'm calculating the time and displaying it in bar for each hour. On hovering the bar I need to display the current hour and the next bars hour. For example, the bars will range from 12 -24 pm and on hovering 1 AM I need to show like 1-2 AM, similarly on hovering 3 AM I need to show 3-4AM. I used the map to iterate the hours and value. Using moment I tried with add hour: 1 its not working.

The code I used using react-moment, on consoling hourValue I'm getting the same hours value Even after adding 1hour.IS there any way to do it?

```
const hourValue = <Moment add={{ minutes : '60' }} format ='HH A'>{value.hours}</Moment>;
```

Comment: Can you please replicate it in codepen and I'll check it out.

Comment: What exactly you want to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer instead of String in the minutes property

```
const hourValue = <Moment add={{ minutes : 60 }} format ='HH A'>{value.hours}</Moment>;
```